# Are there LaTeX packages for working with Toulmin diagrams?

Tags: diagrams

The [Toulmin model of argumentation](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~digger/305/toulmin_model.htm) allows you to present the logical structure of a statement in a visual form.

Are there LaTeX packages, which allow to work with such diagrams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And how easy it is with `tikz`? Here is how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw,minimum width=2.1cm,minimum
                height=2.1cm,text width=2.1cm,font=\raggedright},
         line/.style = {draw,thick, shorten >=3mm,shorten <= 3mm}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [block] (a) {Grounds,\\ Reasons \\ or Evidence};
    \node[block,right = 4cm of a] (b)  {Qualifier};
    \node[block,right = 2cm of b] (c)  {Claim};
    \node[block,below = 1.5cm of a,xshift=1.8cm] (d)  {Warrant};
    \node[block,below = 1.5cm of b,xshift=-0.8cm] (e)  {Warrant};
    \node[block,below = 1cm of d] (f)  {Backing};

    \path[line] (a) -- (b);
    \path[line] (a-|d) -- (d) ;
    \path[line] (b.south-|e.75) -- (e.75) ;
    \path[line] (b) -- (c);
    \path[line] (d) -- (f);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`Tikz` would work well, you can see [examples such as this one](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/porter-model/) that show how to create boxes and text. If I didn't have finals in six hours I'd draw your example diagram!

The basic structure in `Tikz` (for this kind of diagram at least) is to allow you to create named nodes, create a shape around them (by passing parameters to the node itself) and then you can link them by name—this allows the drawing to be edited and maintained instead of drawing by absolute position, which can break if anything small changes.

Answer (score 2):

I have started developing a package for argumentation schemes.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{argumentation}
\begin{document}

\begin{toulmin}
  \fact{fact}
  \warrant{warrant}
  \backing{backing}
  \qualifier{qualifier}
  \rebuttal{rebuttal}
  \conclusion{conclusion}
\end{toulmin}

\end{document}
```

[image: toulmin scheme]

You can find it on https://github.com/chrisersen/argumentation. Feedback welcome.